# How to uninstall python 2.7 from terminal?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, installation

[terminal message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIkY2.png)

I have been having issues with installing things in the terminal Python related like: https://github.com/RomelTorres/alpha_vantage

I did try to uninstall python and install Python 3.8.2 but when I do "python --version" I get Python 2.7.16.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have to uninstall it, instead of using the keyword `python`, try  `python3`. `python3 --version` will most likely give the version 3.8.2 if you have it installed. On most Linux distributions, and I'm assuming on macOS too, `python` refers to Python 2 instead of Python 3 for backwards compatibility, so you have to explicitly tell it to use Python 3.

Comment: When I do "python3 --version" I get "Python 3.8.2". How do I tell it to use Python 3?

Comment: Instead of using "python" to run scripts, use "python3". Or, if you're installing that library via pip, use "pip3" instead of "pip".

Comment: GENIUS! Thank you.

Comment: @UmmaromanaSama You can also use `python3 -m pip install ...` to make sure the pip you are using is the one compatible with that Python version.